# zmq.node: invalid ELF header for Nodejs

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, zeromq

I'm building a docker image for a Node.js project and among other dependecies it has `"zeromq": "^5.2.0"` (which most likely caused the error below).

The dockerfile is:

```
#  We are using the latest Node.js distribution with Long Term Support (LTS) as of 11/04/2020.
FROM node:14.15

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "dist/src/app.js" ]
```

When running a docker instance I receive the following logs

```
server /usr/src/app
> node dist/src/app.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1122
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: /usr/src/app/node_modules/zeromq/build/Release/zmq.node: invalid ELF header
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1122:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/zeromq/lib/index.js:6:11)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bitcoin-broadcast-server@1.3.0 server: `node dist/src/app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bitcoin-broadcast-server@1.3.0 server script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-03-05T11_31_06_652Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bitcoin-broadcast-server@1.3.0 start: `npm run server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bitcoin-broadcast-server@1.3.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-03-05T11_31_06_791Z-debug.log
```

The error message (`Error: /usr/src/app/node_modules/zeromq/build/Release/zmq.node: invalid ELF header`) points out the the ZeroMQ binary is corrupted, but I can't find any fix for it.

Comment: How are you launching the container?  (Do you have volume mounts that replace the `node_modules` tree in the image with something else?)